# Solspace User Notification emails

Tags: solspace-user

I'm using Solspace User and I’m hoping this is just something simple I’ve overlooked or can’t find, but I’m trying to send the notification email when a new user registers to multiple addresses.

Am I correct in saying that I go to Members > Preferences and enter the addresses in the “Email Address for Notification” field?

I’ve done this, but it’s only sending to the first address on the list.  I’ve taken over this site from someone else, so I might just not be putting them in the right place.

Thanks,

Comment: yes, you are correct. Are you entering emails with comma separated as instructed.

Comment: Hi Bhashkar, thanks for your help, turns out everything was ok, it was just going into the clients spam folder.